# SonarQube 5.1.1 LDAP authentication is not working

Tags: authentication, ldap, sonarqube

I am using Sonar 5.1.1 version. I am trying to Link the Sonar with LDAP server.
For this these are the properties i am givig.

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword=true
ldap.url=ldap://***
ldap.windows.auth=false

ldap.user.baseDn=CN=Development,DC=abc,DC=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

ldap.group.baseDn=CN=Development,DC=abc,DC=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
```

## In The sonar.log

```
LdapGroupMapping{baseDn=CN=Development,DC=abc,DC=com, idAttribute=cn, requiredUserAttributes=[dn], request=(&(objectClass=group)(**member={0}**))}
2015.11.25 18:53:04 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection on ldap://****: OK
2015.11.25 18:53:04 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm started
2015.11.25 18:53:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2015.11.25 18:53:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index rules
2015.11.25 18:53:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activeRules
2015.11.25 18:53:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2015.11.25 18:53:05 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Cleaning quality gate conditions
2015.11.25 18:53:05 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel] Register technical debt model
2015.11.25 18:53:05 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
```

Here Above member is coming 0, and when i am trying to login from sonar web UI, I am getting this message in log.

```
ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception Java::OrgSonarApiUtils::SonarException: Unable to retrieve details for user maruti in <default>
```

Comment: What do you get when you execute directly the following request in your LDAP: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={maruti})) ?

Comment: I am new to this LDAP and Sonar, can u tell me how can i execute this request directly to LDAP server, and 

#ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))

This property should be same always, and whaat does it signify?..